# Android layout Issue - showing differently on different devices.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-api-levels

I have some xml which working fine with api level above 17 but showing differently on phones api below same. My minSDK is 15.

> **Should i make layout v-17 , v-16 , v-15 separately or is there any other way around which works for all three at once.?**

**XML showing different behaviour on devices:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/verify_number_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_name_id"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <customViews.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/tv_state_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/country_code_text"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:font="OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <customViews.EditTextPlus
            android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_number_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/textview_color_selector"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:font="OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <customViews.ButtonPlus
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:textColor="@color/textview_color_selector"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:font="Oswald-Light.ttf" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/text_color"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**outline.xml drawable used above and showing differently :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="0.7pt"
        android:color="#FFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="55dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="55dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="55dp"
        android:topRightRadius="55dp" />
</shape>
```

**above xml image on device above 17:**
[image]

image on below api 17:

[image]
**Please suggest some way around.**

Comment: post your `customViews.ButtonPlus` code...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 custom views are just for Typeface. That's it.
public class ButtonPlus extends AppCompatButton {
    public ButtonPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);

    }
}

Comment: try using `extends Button`  instead...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 tried . Didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the corners Drawable and change the Radius.Need to decrease the Radius size like this-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="0.7pt"
        android:color="#FFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

Thanks

Comment: It helped. Thanks alot.

Comment: Thanks to you too.@young_08

Answer (score 2):

I think your corners value is to large(larger than half of view height) in your background drawable.

Try like this:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="23dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="23dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="23dp"
    android:topRightRadius="23dp" />
```

Comment: actually, hard coded these values were the  problem. It resolved now. Thanks. I will appreciate if you upvote the question. Thanks again